# Rows of graphs into one row in tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop

I am very new to Tableau and can't find an answer to what is probably a relatively easy question:

I am trying to plot a variable by hour/day of the week, and splitting this by participant (study ID). I get the below snippet in Tableau:

[Tableau](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuVU1.png)

Instead of a row of graphs per study ID, I want each study ID line to be **on the same row of graphs**. I was able to do it pretty easily in Python for reference:

[Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BF4Gy.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Brad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move Study Id from the row shelf to the color shelf